# SharePoint alternatives which are built on .net technology

Tags: .net, sharepoint

I am searching for an enterprise application which has mainly the following features:-

- .NET based extensibility framework
- Collaboration facility
- Business process management
- Document & content management

I need to evaluate other alternatives to SharePoint, but i need these enterprise systems to be built on asp.net technology. Can anyone suggest such software so that i can read more about them.
BR

Comment: Why does it have to be built on .NET technology? Are you going to be modifying it? If so, you will also need an appropriately permissive licence. Or do you mean it must have an extensibility framework that allows development in .NET? Or something else?

Comment: As we are partners with Microsoft and all our expertise are within .net technology. it does not need to be open source but if we need to extend it or implement new plugins or libraries to be able to do so  using .net which will be the same language used to build the software itself.

Comment: You should probably edit the question to include a ".NET based extensibility framework" as one of your required features, for clarity. The definition of "Enterprise software" is sufficiently vague as to not necessarily include that ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that [Sense/Net](http://www.sensenet.com/) is an open source alternative to SharePoint. Having not used it I cannot comment on the stability, performance or robustness.

You can find more about it on CodePlex: http://sensenet.codeplex.com/